# How to not change file owner and group when Netbeans uploads a file to an Ubuntu FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, netbeans

I am running a vsftpd FTP server on my Ubuntu server, but when I setup my Netbeans web project to upload files to it, it changes the owner and group to `karel:karel`, which is very bad, because the `www-data` user now cannot read the file and the webserver stops working.

I login to the FTP server using my Ubuntu account "karel", with `local_enable` enabled. I am running the Netbeans project from a Windows 10 machine.

Is there a setting to disable owner and group change on file upload? I need it to stay `karel:www-data`. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711918/how-to-control-the-file-permissions-when-the-netbeans-php-plugin-uploads-a-file/13910384#13910384) but all the answers, including using the `local_umask` setting, only talk about changing file privileges, my problem is changing it's group.

`chown_username` is for upload by anonymous user, which I don't want. I can delete the user group `karel` if it would help, I don't need it for anything.

Other solution would be to allow everyone to read from the files, it is only a virtual machine that only I have access to anyway, but I would rather do it the proper way and not change file group after upload. For example, WinSCP doesn't change the file group on upload.

Comment: What protocol are you using with WinSCP? Also FTP – or SFTP?

Comment: One solution is to add your `www-data` user to the `karel` group, or better use a specific id for upload and add `www-data` to its group.

Comment: I'm using normal FTP with both Netbeans and WinSCP. @xenoid "better use a specific id for upload and add www-data to its group" that could work, but how exactly? Let's say I make a user `web-upload` for example and put them in group `www-data`. Then the owner and group would be set to `web-upload:www-data` and the web server can now read it, but now I (the user `karel`) can't, unless I'm also in the `www-data` group. But if the setting for group is only to read, then I can't write into the files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Netbeans. But if the screenshot in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/711918/850848#39050847) to [How to control the file permissions when the netbeans php plugin uploads a file with FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/711918/850848) is relevant, then I believe you need to check:

> Upload Files Directly (temporary file is not used)

When the option is unchecked, a new file with the default ownership is created. While when it is checked, the existing file with existing ownership will be overwritten. What is an equivalent to WinSCP behavior.

A disadvantage is, that your website may stop working for the duration of the upload.

Comment: Wow it actually worked. Too bad I have to use the "direct upload" method, which is apparently unsave, but it's better than nothing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there are two settings of interest in the [vsftpd config](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html):

```
file_open_mode
    The permissions with which uploaded files are created. 
    Umasks are applied on top of this value. You may wish to 
    change to 0777 if you want uploaded files to be executable.

    Default: 0666 

local_umask
    The value that the umask for file creation is set to for local users. 
    NOTE! If you want to specify octal values, remember the "0" prefix
    otherwise the value will be treated as a base 10 integer!

    Default: 077
```

So you can either:

- Set the files as world readable and your server can user them without changes
- Set the files as group-readable and either:

  - add the server id to the 'karel' group
  - put yourself in the `www-data` group (nothing in Unix/Linux mandates that your default group must be the same as your id, and if the main purpose of your `karel` id on your server is managing the server, putting it the www-data group makes sense).

Note that in 2020, it has become common practice to share a Git repo between you and the server, and to use Git hooks to deploy the code on the server when actions happen on a given branch.

Comment: Interesting options, I ended up setting the files as world readable since I am the only user on that machine anyway. Git is no good in this case, since I needed to develop on that ubuntu server in real time, so I would end up with 20 commits named "changed form process function".